# Animate react tabbed navigation bar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I want to create a nice sliding animation when a user clicks to another tab. I am using React and React router. Im using flexbox to make the tabs dynamically fill up the space of the container, since different users will see a different number of tabs depending on what they are permissioned to see. How can I add animations when I don't know the number of tabs there will be?

Im looking for an effect similar to this. https://codepen.io/burntcustard/pen/PwGgJz

Here is my React Tab component:

```
return (
  <div className={STYLES.tabbedNavbar}>
    { tabs.map( (tab, i) => {
      return (
        <div className={STYLES.container}>
          <Link
            key={i}
            to={tab.routePath}
            className={STYLES.tab}
            activeClassName={STYLES.activeTab}
            target={tab.newTab ? "_blank" : ""}>
            <div className={STYLES.label} onClick={this.handleClick}> { tab.label } </div>
          </Link>
           <div className={STYLES.slider} ref={ ref => this.slider = ref }></div>
        </div>
      );
```

Here is my sass for the React component:

```
.tabbedNavbar
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between
  width: 100%
  border-bottom: 2px solid $medium-gray
  line-height: 16px
  margin: 20px 0 30px 0

.tab
  min-width: 105px
  text-align: center
  color: $header-gray
  &:hover
    color: $header-gray
  &:focus
    text-decoration: none
    color: $header-gray

.activeTab
  color: $base-green
  border-bottom: 4px solid $base-green
  margin-bottom: -2px
  &:hover
    color: $base-green
  &:focus
    color: $base-green
    text-decoration: none
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to, onClick, get the `left` position of the tab relative to the container. Then, set `left` on your slider to the same value. Should work with however many tabs you have. Make sure to add a `transition: position 500ms ease` to your slider to make the movement smooth.

EDIT:

[**Quick and dirty JSFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/87543/)

Comment: this is great! only issue is that when the screen is at all resized, the slider is completely disconnected from the active tab :/

Comment: You can add a resize event handler to the page that re-runs the function. [Updated the JSFiddle to track resize events.](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/87964/) Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Ahh, this is so close to working. The only issue here is that I am creating the tabs dynamically so I don't know the number of tabs within the component to do the binding on ( `bind(this, 0)` ). Shown in the example code, just edited what was originally there.

Comment: @Veronica If you are storing your buttons in a list, when you `map` over the button you can use the index position and it should be the same as the DOM index postiion.

Comment: I'm unsure of how the syntax for this would work in terms of changing the way you are attaching the activeBtn to whatever button is active via react router.

Comment: running the code in its current state after wrapping the `Link` in a button that I map though, I'm getting an error about using super()

Comment: @Veronica Sounds like a separate issue that you should make a new post about. Hope you get this working.